# Translations for 척하면 척이다

Tags: vocabulary, translation, examples

An intimate friend and native Korean speaker explained that I should have added a word in what I said to her, but she summarized with

> 척하면 척이다

I think I get what she meant, but I began wondering what different ways we express this in english.  As an example, I'm guessing this might be one way to translate it:

> I'm picking up what you're putting down.

but since the phrase itself may be subject to its own meaning, nuance may best be represented with a list of suitable translations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been discussing this with a group of well educated, native speaking Koreans. I believe the best translation will be:

> **I knew what you meant.**

Because, the phrase seems to be used when a few words were spoken but more are understood, either based on context or some other mutual understanding. That's probably why my close friend understood what I meant; because we are close enough that I didn't have to complete my sentence perfectly to have communicated what I was thinking.

Perhaps some other less likely candidates might include:

> I know what you mean.
>
> I get it.
>
> I'm following you.
>
> I'm with you.
>
> I know where you're going.
>
> No need to say more.